# How would I target this div using CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

In the code below, how would I target the second `div.b` using CSS?

```
<div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In this particular instance, you could use the [adjacent sibling combinator, `+`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators).

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/WvL88/)

```
.b + .b {
   color:red;
}
```

---

The above assumes there are no more than two, adjacent `.b` elements. If this wasn't the case, the [general sibling combinator, `~`,](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) would be more useful assuming there are still only two `.b` elements.

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/unRFu/)

```
.b ~ .b {
    color:red;
}
```

---

As an alternative, you could also use the following, which will work with multiple `.b` elements, regardless of position. Initially, use `.b ~ .b` to set the styling of the second, targeted element. You would then need to use `.b ~ .b ~ .b` to reset the styling of the `.b` elements following the second `.b` element.

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/g2YLn/)

```
.b ~ .b {
    color:red;
}
.b ~ .b ~ .b {
    color:initial;
}
```

This should theoretically work in all instances, for example:

```
<div class="a">1a</div>
<div class="a">2a</div>
<div class="a">3a</div>
<div class="b">1b</div>
<div class="a">4a</div>
<div class="b">2b</div> <!-- This would be styled red.. -->
<div class="b">3b</div>
```

It's also worth noting that the value [`initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) isn't supported in IE. You could therefore use `color:#000` to [reset the color back to the defaults](http://jsfiddle.net/zZw8y/). Alternatively, `inherit` [would work too](http://jsfiddle.net/x3ya9/).

As a more practical example, you could use something like this:

[**EAXMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yQkV7/)

```
.b ~ .b {
    width:200px;
    background:blue;
    color:#fff;
}
.b ~ .b ~ .b {
    width:auto;
    background:transparent;
    color:#000;
}
```

Comment: This works as long as the HTML doesn't contain any other elements with class `b`: http://jsfiddle.net/WvL88/1/

Comment: The use of `+` also assumes that there are no more than 2 consecutive `.b` elements.

Comment: And Firefox still uses the prefix `-moz-initial` if I'm not wrong.

Comment: @Adrift: Oh, that's neat. Hopefully it won't take too long for IE to learn it eventually.

Answer (score 14):

There is also another way of achieving what you want to do.

```
div > :nth-child(5){

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WvL88/3/